# Can we add jobs to running schedular in ApSchedular

Tags: python, apscheduler

I started Background scheduler in one file and ran it. Then from other file I accessed scheduler instance and added job. What my thought was the instance will add the job and it will run. I am new to this scheduling mechanisms. What I did is 
On one file `Main.py`

```
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

class Main:
    a = 2
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

From other file `Bm.py`

```
from Main import Main

class Bm(Main) :

    def timed_job():
         print 'aa'

    Main.sched.add_job(timed_job,'interval',seconds=1)
```

I thought this would do, but it didnot.I need to this way from seperate file because I need to make a task manager which would run jobs and I need to be able to add or remove jobs anytime needed.SO how can we add and remove jobs to/from running apscheduler?
**UPDATE :** 
This is confusing. I added a function `printme` on `Main.py` and did `sched.add_job(printme,'interval',seconds=5)`, it prints `me` as expected but when I run `Bm.py` it also prints `me`, when it was supposed to print `aa`

```
def printme():
    print 'me'

while True:
  #  time.sleep(5)
    sched.add_job(printme,'interval',seconds=5)
    if (input() is 'q'):
        sched.shutdown()
```

Comment: is last code block declared in `Main` class?

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo yes

Comment: guessing with very small information you gave. apscheduler could throwing the exception while trying to execute your job. Because of that you are not getting the result you expected

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo Sorry I forgot to update, but the reason was that I was running infinite loop from main class ( I came from Java, so had no idea that just creating instance of main class would trigger infinite loop ). Removed while loop from main class and ran main class and then Bm class, now it works